# Error when running client for Minecraft forge from IntelliJ

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I don't know if I changed something accidentally, but normally things run just fine before.
Yesterday, I clicked runClient on Gradle, and it did not open minecraft on forge. It could not. The error is this:
`[error occurred during error reporting (), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff9d32b9b30]`

I tried to get a log, and this is what I ended up with:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe02b10590, pid=2248, tid=16132
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8+7 (17.0.8+7) (build 17.0.8+7)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8+7 (17.0.8+7, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x190590]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------
I cannot add the rest because it's too big.
```

I've tried clearing the cache, reinstalling IntelliJ, reinstalling Java, and restarting my PC.
Nothing has worked so far.

Normally, clicking 'runClient' should just load up a small window with MC on it. And the mod I developed should be in there. Last week it worked fine, but now it just doesn't. Nothing changed in the hardware of my computer, I checked for a corrupt OS but it isn't that either.

Comment: Turns out it was the graphics driver.... Thank you!